# Disable jQuery fadeIn effect for mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, optimization, fadein

On my site, I have a fadeIn effect for my #header using jQuery. How can I disable the effect for mobile optimization? Below is the code used for the effect.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 400) {
            $("#header").fadeIn(200);
        }

        if ($(window).scrollTop() < 399) {
            $("#header").fadeOut(200);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
// change 320 to required min width
if ( $(window).width() > 320 ) {
    // your scroll code here

}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Maybe I'm copying it wrong. Can you code with the scroll code?

Comment: @TroyMcClure, check the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9zvs6m6p/), although I don't know how your HTML looks like it might help.

Comment: Perfect! I got it to work by increasing the window width to 500. Thank you @Danijel